# Set attributes for root element on Symfony2 form builder

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

Hi guys i`m using symfony2 form builder and i want to add attributes on the form element the desired effect is something like this:

```
<form
    data-login="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('login_check'); ?>"                
    data-register="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('register'); ?>"
    action="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('login_check'); ?>"
    method="post"
    id="ajaxLoginForm"
    name="login_form">
```

I`m using php templates. How can i achive this?

Thanks for the time.
If you have questions ask them in the comment section.
Best Regards,
Georgi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible by acting on the `FormBuilder` the same way you do for customizing the form fields. To do it for the root form element, on the `setDefaultOptions` of your form class (the one which extends `AbstractType`) you should return (amongst the others) the `attr` key, with the corresponding value being an associative array of attribute names => values:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'attr' => array('id' => 'ajaxLoginForm'),
        ...
    ));
}
```

For the form `name` attribute, just implement (on the same class)

```
public function getName() {

    return 'login_form';
}
```

After implementing the above methods properly, the attributes should be rendered correctly without you having to perform any modifications on your templates or form theme.

**Note:** you may have to inject the router component in the form (or pass it as an option when instantiating it) in order to create the routes you need for your `data-login` and `data-register` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

For attributes use

```
<?php echo $view['form']->form($form, array(
    'attr' => array(
        'data-login' => $view['router']->generate('login_check'),                
        'data-register' => $view['router']->generate('register'),
        // etc...
    ),
)) ?>
```

For specific attributes you can use

```
// In form class
$builder->setAction('/login_check');
$builder->setMethod('post');
```